# React delete item and updating list

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react redux for my app. I have list of products, which renders with function:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(productsActions.fetchProducts(categoryId, sortBy, searchValue));
    }, [dispatch, categoryId, sortBy, searchValue]);
```

When I delete product with this function:

```
 const deleteProduct = React.useCallback((productId) => {
        dispatch(productsActions.deleteProduct(productId));
    }, [dispatch]);
```

I need to renew my page to see that product was deleted.

How is better to update the list of product without renewing page?

This is all code for products page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Header } from '../components/Header';
import { LeftMenu } from '../components/LeftMenu';
import * as productsActions from '../store/actions/products';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Products = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products.products);
    const categoryId = undefined;
    const sortBy = undefined;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(productsActions.fetchProducts(categoryId, sortBy, searchValue));
    }, [dispatch, categoryId, sortBy, searchValue]);

    const deleteProduct = React.useCallback((productId) => {
        dispatch(productsActions.deleteProduct(productId));
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <div class="wrapper">
            <Header />
            <article class="main">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="search-bar">
                        <input name="search" searchData={searchValue} onChange={e => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} value={searchValue} className="searchOpen" placeholder="Search products..." />
                        <Link class="add-button" to="add-product">Add product</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item--4-4">
                        <div class="item-title">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Image</th>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Category</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {products.map(product => (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="#">{product._id}</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#"><img class="product-image" src={product.imageUrl} /></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#">{product.title}</a></td>
                                            <td>{product.category.title}</td>
                                            <td>{product.price}</td>
                                            <td><span class="status">{product.status}</span></td>
                                            <td><button onClick={() => deleteProduct(product._id)}><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
                                            </button>
                                                <button><ion-icon name="create-outline"></ion-icon></button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                    )}

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <div class="pagination">
                            <p class="pagination-label">1-10 of 10</p>
                            <a href="#">
                                <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </article>
            <LeftMenu />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my Actions for products:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Product from '../../models/product';

export const FETCH_PRODUCTS = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS';
export const ADD_PRODUCT = 'ADD_PRODUCT';
export const DELETE_PRODUCT = 'DELETE_PRODUCT';

export const fetchProducts = (categoryId, sortBy, title) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products', data: { categoryId, sortBy, title } });
            const resData = await response.data.products;
            const loadedProducts = [];
            for (const key in resData) {
                loadedProducts.push(new Product(
                    resData[key]._id,
                    resData[key].title,
                    resData[key].imageUrl,
                    resData[key].description,
                    resData[key].price,
                    resData[key].status,
                    resData[key].categoryId,
                ))
            }
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRODUCTS, products: loadedProducts });
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

export const addProduct = (product) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/add-product', data: { product } });
        const resData = await response.data;
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_PRODUCT,
            product: resData
        });
    };
};

export const deleteProduct = (productId) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/delete-product', data: { productId } });
        console.log('RESPO:', response)
        const resData = await response.data;
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_PRODUCT,
            product: resData
        });
    };
};
```

This is my Reducer for products:

```
import {
    FETCH_PRODUCTS,
    ADD_PRODUCT,
    DELETE_PRODUCT
} from '../actions/products';

const initialState = {
    products: [],
    loading: true
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS:

            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.products,
                loading: false
            }
        case ADD_PRODUCT:

            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.product
            }
        case DELETE_PRODUCT:

            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.product
            }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Are the products in the redux mapped to the props of a component? If yes, then the component will rerender to display the new products. Add more code to the question.

Comment: I am using useSelector:     const products = useSelector(state => state.products.products);

Comment: I updated post and put all code for the products page

Comment: Can you share the code of your Redux `actions` and `reducer`, please?

Comment: Updated post! Added Actions and Reducers for products

Comment: @Oleg Does this `'http://localhost:3000/api/delete-product'` give the updated products list?

Comment: @RameshReddy No its deleting specific product when I click button next to product

Comment: @Oleg Yep it's for deleting a product but what do you get in `response.data` for this API?

Comment: @RameshReddy Thank you for the point. I updated code and know getting product list on delete from api. But still I am getting products with deleted one. I guess something with state

Comment: @Oleg I don't see any issue with the React code. Make sure that the `delete-product` endpoint returns the updated list rather than the old list. You can also try dispatching the `fetchProducts` action after deleting a product.

Comment: @RameshReddy I just did not updated my state in the reducer. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for others.
I forgot to update state in my reducer when I was deleting product.

So, in the products reducer should be filter for current state, which removes deleted product from state:

```
case DELETE_PRODUCT:

            const upds = state.products.filter(items => {
                return items._id !== action.productId;
            });

            return {
                ...state,
                products: upds
            }
```